# Call a function from a thread and RS 232

Tags: c++, multithreading, serial-port

I am programming in Visual Studio 2008 in console application. I am working with a display that is communicated by Rs 232.

I have a thread that counts from 0 to 10 seconds. When reaches 10 I want to turn off the displays backlight. For that I have a function that is called from the thread. The called from the thread is well because I know that the code of the function is executed.

But code of turning the backlight off does not work when the function is called from the thread and it works the it is called from another place. Any ideas?
Thanks.

```
void FunctionBacklightoff(HANDLE portHandle,DWORD bytesTransmitted)
{
    cout << "backoff";
    WriteFile(portHandle, backlight_off , 4, &bytesTransmitted, NULL);//does not work when 
    //it is called from the thread. It works when it is called from wmain()
}

DWORD WINAPI solo_thread(void* arg)
{ 
   int Counter = 0;
   printf( "In second thread...\n" );

   while ( true )
   {
       if(Counter<10)
       {
           Counter++;
           Sleep(1000);
       }
       else 
       {
           printf( "Han pasado 10 segundos; Counter:-> %d\n", Counter );
           FunctionBacklightoff(portHandle,bytesTransmitted);//from here doesnt work
           Counter = 0;
       }

   }

return 0;
}

int wmain(void)
{
    hThread =CreateThread(NULL, 0, solo_thread,NULL ,0, NULL);
    //inicialize rs232 communications...
    retVal = PortOpen(&portHandle, 115200);
    if (!retVal)
    {
        printf("Could not open CoM port");
        getchar();
    }   
    else
    {

        printf("CoM port opened successfully");
        retVal = FALSE;
    }
    FunctionBacklightoff(portHandle,bytesTransmitted);//from here works
}
```

Comment: Please share complete source code that reproduces your issue. Your code does not even call `FunctionBacklightoff`.

Comment: Yes, FunctionBacklightoff is called from the thread because 'cout <<backoff' is displayed in the console.

Comment: Allright, but then you posted here different code than you test!

Comment: sorry a lot, i have edit it.

Comment: Thanks, what about `GetLastError` value after `WriteFile` was called? And how many bytes were transmitted (value of `bytesTransmitted` after `WriteFile`?)

Comment: GetLastError does not return anything; and I declare bytestransmitted like that: 'DWORD bytesTransmitted = 0;   '

Comment: It is strange that the function works when it is called from wmain and does not work when it is called from the thread.

Comment: `GetLastError` *must* return something. What is value of `bytesTransmitted` after the `WriteFile` finishes?

Comment: `bytesTransmitted` after Writefile is 4. For getlasterror sorry but i cant find anything.

Comment: Then your data must have been sent successfuly and `FunctionBacklightoff` works fine! What can you see on your serial port? I bet your backlight data will be there.

Comment: If the data is sent why isnt turning off the display?

Comment: I have no idea. When you add 10s delay between port opening and `FunctionBacklightoff` in `wmain`, does it work?

Comment: Yes, it works well.

Comment: Sorry, but due to some changes I made I made a mistake. bytesTrasmitted is 0 in the function and also in the thread. In wmain is 4.

Answer (score 0):

How `portHandle` is declared? Looks like it's static field so thread could simply not get change that happen after it's creation. To be sure you could mark `portHandle` as `volatile` or change the order of operations:

```
//Open port so we will be sure that postHandle is populated before thread starts.
retVal = PortOpen(&portHandle, 115200);
hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, solo_thread,NULL ,0, NULL);
```

Also you have a BUG that your wmain will exit before thread being executed. To fix that you should place following code right before `wmain` last bracket:

```
WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
```

Note that because your thread have `while(true)` without break condition it will run forever and each 10 seconds will switch off backlight. If this was not intentional add a `break` into else.

Comment: this won't probably fix the problem since data are being sent (`bytesTransmitted` equals to 4 after `WriteFile` finishes)

Comment: Porthandle is declared as  `HANDLE portHandle;`.It is okey?

Comment: Yes, the while true is intentional because the user turns on the display.

Comment: @Andermutu Add a print that output value of `portHandle` in `FunctionBacklightoff` so it should be the same in wmain and in thread.

Comment: Sorry, but due to some changes I made I made a mistake. bytesTrasmitted is 0 in the function and also in the thread. In wmain is 4.

Comment: @Andermutu ok, then you should check `GetLastError` after `WriteFile` finishes. Also as noted by @j2ko comparing `portHandle` in `wmain` and in thread should be useful.

Comment: Sorry but, with GetLastError what should appear in the console?

Comment: @Andermutu [WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx) docs contin remark about `GetLastError` purpose

Comment: try starting with `std::cout << "GetLastError()=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;`, put it immediately after `WriteFile` call and post results here